# prove that $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} 2^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}} =1 $ without using continuity of functions

Tags: calculus

Prove that $$ \lim_{n\to\infty} 2^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}} =1 $$ I tryed to solve this using the sandwich theorem and the fact that $\lim 2^{\frac{1}{{n}}} =1 $. We did not learn continuity of functions so I am not alowed to use this. Any suggestions?

Comment: Hint, use the fact that the logarithm is continuous to write this as $exp(\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\ln(2))$.

Comment: @MichaelBurr I wrote in the question that I am not alowed to use continuity of functions

Comment: This becomes $2$ raised to a power near $0$, and $2^0=1$.

Comment: $\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty}2^{1/m}=1$

Change of variables $m^2\rightarrow n$?

Comment: @Turbo can you explain why we can change variables?

Comment: @Turbo you are using some claim that I am missing?

Answer (score 6):

First: $2^{1/n} \to 1.$ Proof: Let $2^{1/n} = 1 + a_n.$ Then $a_n > 0$ and the binomial theorem gives

$$2 = (1+a_n)^n = 1 + na_n + \cdots \ge 1 + na_n.$$

Thus $0< na_n \le 1 \implies a_n \to 0 \implies 2^{1/n}\to 1.$

As for $2^{1/\sqrt n}:$ Let $\epsilon>0.$ From the above there exists $m$ such that $1< 2^{1/m} = 2^{1/\sqrt {m^2}}<1+\epsilon.$ Because $p< q \implies 2^p< 2^q,$ we have $1< 2^{1/\sqrt {n}}<1+\epsilon$ for $n\ge m^2.$ Thus $2^{1/\sqrt n}\to 1.$

Comment: Well done!  +1. You might have considered using Bernoulli's Inequality directly and had the "squeeze" immediately on.  - Mark

Answer (score -2):

Think about this intuitively, as n approaches infinity, what does the value of 1/sqrt(n) become? Well, I think we agree that as n approaches infinity, the square root of n becomes infinity. So, what is 1 divided a really really big number? It is a really small number aka zero; 2 to the zero-th power is one. Therefore, the limit is 1.

Comment: intuitively it is clear. I am looking for formal proof